# Android studio recycler view not working with no errors

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So I was trying to implement recycler view. I have seen some guides on it, but I still don't quite understand it. My code got no errors, it's just the activity doesn't show any of the items. It's all empty.

**GalleryActivity.java** This is my targeted activity to show the recycler view on

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    final String image_titles[] =
            {
                    "Img1",
                    "Img2",
                    "Img3",
                    "Img4",
                    "Img5",
                    "Img7",
                    "Img8"
            };

final Integer image_ids[] =
        {
                R.drawable.img1,
                R.drawable.img2,
                R.drawable.img3,
                R.drawable.img4,
                R.drawable.img5,
                R.drawable.img7,
                R.drawable.img8
        };
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_gallery);

    Toolbar tb = findViewById(R.id.galleryToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);

    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.imagegallery);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2));
    ArrayList<CreateList> createLists = prepareData();
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), createLists);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Gallery");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}


ArrayList<CreateList> prepareData()
{
    ArrayList<CreateList> images = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i< image_titles.length; i++)
    {
        CreateList createList = new CreateList();
        createList.setImage_title(image_titles[i]);
        createList.setImage_ID(image_ids[i]);
        images.add(createList);
    }
    return images;
}
}
```

**MyAdapter.java** This is the adapter, I still don't quite understand all what's going here, but here is the code

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList;
    private Context context;
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList) {
    this.galleryList = galleryList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
{
    android.view.View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_adapter, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.title.setText(galleryList.get(i).getImage_title());
    viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    viewHolder.img.setImageResource((galleryList.get(i).getImage_ID()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return galleryList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    private TextView title;
    private ImageView img;
    LinearLayout galleryLayout;
    public ViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);

        title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        galleryLayout =(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.galleryLayout);
    }


}
}
```

**CreateList.java** creating the list in a seperate class

```
package com.example.myapplication;


public class CreateList
{
    private String image_title;
    private Integer image_id;

    public String getImage_title() {
        return image_title;
    }

    public void setImage_title(String android_version_name) {
        this.image_title = android_version_name;
    }

    public Integer getImage_ID() {
        return image_id;
    }

    public void setImage_ID(Integer android_image_url) {
        this.image_id = android_image_url;
    }



}
```

**recycler_adapter.xml** Design of the recycler view

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:id="@+id/galleryLayout">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/img3"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

edit:

**fragment_gallery.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.gallery.GalleryFragment">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/imagegallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: hey, I can't see any thing wrong with the code, get the lengths of images titles, arrayList and the adapter and check if they are correct.

Comment: Please, show the contents of fragment_gallery.xml

Comment: @art i edited it providing the xml for fragment_gallery

Comment: How are you launchIng `GalleryActivity`, exactly? That is, what code are you using to get that onscreen?

Comment: @MikeM.U might have misunderstood, actually the gallery activity shows up but only the recycler view doesn't show i only got gallery activity with the action bar up there with no recycler view

Comment: @MikeM.I'm not sure of this but i think actually the recycler view shows up but the items inside are the ones that aren't loaded for some reason

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying, but there are discrepancies in your description. If you were to start that `GalleryActivity` as is, with the given `fragment_gallery` layout, it would crash at at least the `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Gallery");` line. It would never get to a point where you would even see your layout. I have a suspicion that you're not actually using `GalleryActivity`.

Comment: That doesn't really help. What specific code do you run when you "click on gallery"?

Comment: Okay i checked the logs whenever i click on gallery it says:
'  E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout  '

Comment: Yep, you'll get that log message if you're doing what I suspect.

Comment: @MikeM.Ye that's the actual problem, so when i created the project i did make it the navigation drawer activity provided from AS, i started the application to check what is provided and i saw that i can navigate through different fragments on each menu item but i didn't actually understand that the fragment doesn't actually open Fragments

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry for this mistake i'm still new to Android still learning stuff, and thanks for help really!

Answer (score 0):

After rv.setAdapter(adapter); also provide adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
We have to give this line to notify the adapter.

Comment: It didn't work for me actually still the same problem